# Training tensorflow to find patterns between sets of numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train an AI that, given a set of 90 possible numbers, matches 5 generated numbers(no repetitions and numbers are not generated randomly).
This is the code:

```
from numpy import test
import tensorflow as tf
import click
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from itertools import repeat
insert = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90] for i in repeat(None, 33785)]
results = pd.read_csv("datini.csv")
del results['DATA']
del results['LUOGO']
results.drop(columns=results.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
insert_train, insert_test, results_train, results_test = train_test_split(insert, results, test_size=0.2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=insert_train.shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='CategoricalCrossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(insert_train, results_train, epochs=200)
model.evaluate(insert_test, results_test)
```

It gives this error and I don't know how to insert the "fixed data" without creating another dataset.

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'**

Answer (score 0):

Which line is the error at?

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=insert_train.shape))
```

if here, then insert_train.shape is a list. make it into a numpy array so that you can use .shape

```
insert_train = np.array(insert_train)
```

Comment: @Ritwicj Jha Ok, after I added this (you correctely guessed the line where the error occured) this shows up:
**Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 27028, 90), found shape=(None, 90)**

Thanks so much for your help :D <3

It's like the third edit, I used this:

**insert_train = np.array(insert_train).reshape(None, 27028, 90)**

to reshape my numpy array, but got this error message:

**'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

even if None was expected

Comment: what is the shape of insert_train? if you are reshaping it where you don't want to specify the first dimension you should use .reshape(-1,27028,90). I don't think that is the issue though.